# Keyframes CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

**Hello** I'm trying to simulate flip countdown timer But when I wrote the code I discovered that there was a difference between:

```
@keyframes zindex {
0% {
    z-index: 2;
}
5% {
    z-index: 4;
}
100% {
    z-index: 4;
}
}
```

and:

```
@keyframes zindex {
0% {
    z-index: 2;
}
100% {
    z-index: 4;
}
}
```

That when I remove 5% the problem will occurred so I'd like to know why this problem ocurres.

**Here my code:**

```css
body {
    font: normal 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0px 0px -25px;
}
ul#initial {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
}

ul#initial li {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
.first {
    z-index: 3;
}

.second {
    -webkit-animation: zindex 1s 1s linear both;
}
@keyframes zindex {
    0% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    5% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
}
.flipthis {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #bbb;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    color: #fff;
    animation: flipthis 1s linear;
}

.flipthis-down {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: #0034ff;
 color: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: auto;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}

.digit {
 height: 200%;
 font-size: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(224,224,224,0.87);
}

.flipthis-down .digit {
 bottom: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipthis {
 0% {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
 }
}
.flipthis2 {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: #00ff82;
 color: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.flipthis2-down {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: #00f760;
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: auto;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 animation: flipthis-down 1s 1s linear;
}

.flipthis2-down .digit {
 bottom: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipthis-down {
 0% {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
 }
}
a.derp {
 -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
 display: block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <ul id="initial">
            <li class="first">
                <a class="derp">
                    <div class="flipthis">
                        <div class="digit">1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flipthis-down">
                        <div class="digit">1</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="second">
                <a class="derp">
                    <div class="flipthis2">
                        <div class="digit">2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flipthis2-down">
                        <div class="digit">2</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What problem? You mention a problem but don't say what it is.

Comment: difference between keyframes above and what is the techniques between them

Answer (score 0):

The first example reaches the final value of '4' after only 5% of the animation is done, the second example increases the z-index linearly over the specified animation duration.

Adding multiple '%' values tells your browser at what point in time what value should be reached, so your first animation is basically already finished after 5% of the time has passed.